# How to use an array that stores one byte in the fread function(In Triple_DES Algorithm)

Tags: arrays, c, byte, bit, tripledes

I am trying to use the fread function. In the code below, input_text stores values ​​in bit units, but file_size represents the number of bytes. Because of this, wrong values ​​are entered in the input_text array, and I am curious about how to solve this.

```
'''
fseek(Ptr_input, 0, SEEK_END);  
file_size = ftell(Ptr_input);   
fseek(Ptr_input, 0, SEEK_SET); 

char* input_text = (char*)malloc((file_size) * 8 + 64);
if (input_text == NULL) {
    printf("malloc failed.\n");
    fclose(Ptr_input);
    exit(1);
}

fread(input_text, 1, file_size, Ptr_input);`
'''
```

To sum up, what I want to do is to solve an error when trying to save values ​​in the input_text array that stores values ​​in bit units in the fread function, which processes values ​​in byte units.

Comment: The `malloc` call takes the number of *bytes* to allocate as argument, so there's no need to multiply `file_size` with `8`. Or add `64` extra bytes.

Comment: As for your problem, `fread` reads *bytes* into the *byte* array `input_text`. If you want to access individual bits then you need to come up with a set of functions that extracts the bits from the byte array.

Comment: Also, how do you know you get the wrong values? How do you check the values? What is the actual contents of the file, what is the data you expect, and what is the data you get? And remember that it's implementation-defined in `char` is signed or unsigned. If you want to treat a byte as a set of bits, use explicitly unsigned integer types instead. Like `uint8_t`.